Removing DC component from an AC signal
How do I remove a DC component in an AC signal during phase fault in a power system?

What current and Frequency are we talking? In a "power system" you are talking mains power?
In that case I'd personally opt for a transformer.

Have you tried with a capacitor in series?

A series-connected capacitor could cancel the DC component and let through the AC component. But without more details about the circuit, I can't say anything more.

So I have simulated a MATLAB model of failure in transformer but I want to remove the DC component in the ac fault signal
